# Angular2 unit test with debounceTime in component "Cannot use setInterval from within an async zone test"

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, rxjs5

I am trying to test a component that renders background images whenever elements are visible. I detect visibility on scroll an resize events, and to ease the load I'm using `debounceTime` from RxJS. This however is a problem since the unit test fails with

> Failed: Cannot use setInterval from within an async zone test.

I know this is a problem due to the async nature of `debounceTime`, but I'm not sure how to prevent this / mock `debounceTime` for the test.

This is the Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as config from '../../config';
import ListComponentBase from '../../../forminputs/ListComponentBase';

@Component({
    selector: `list-component`,
    template: `
    <a
        *ngFor="let item of data.list"
        class="box"
        routerLink="/edit/{{item._id}}">
        <div class="name" >{{ item.name }}</div>
        <list-item-background
            *ngIf="isVisible[item._id]" [mediaObjectId]="item.coverImageUrl"></list-item-background>
    </a>
    `,
    inputs: ['data', 'id'],
    outputs: ['filter', 'sorting'],
})
export class ListComponent extends ListComponentBase {
    constructor() {
        this.isVisible = {};
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.check();
        if (document.querySelector('nav')){
            this.scroll = Observable
                .fromEvent(document.querySelector('nav'), 'scroll')
                .debounceTime(100).subscribe((event) => {
                    this.checkVisibility();
                });
        }
        this.resize = Observable
            .fromEvent(window, 'resize')
            .debounceTime(100).subscribe((event) => {
                this.checkVisibility();
            });
    }
    check() {
        this.data.list.forEach(item => {
            this.isVisible[item._id] = this.isElementInViewport(document.querySelector(`[data-id="${item._id}"]`));
        });
    }
    isElementInViewport(el) {
        if (!el) return false;
        const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        return (
                rect.top >= 0 &&
                rect.left >= 0 &&
                rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
                rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
        );
    }
}
```

This is the unit test

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TestBed, inject, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

import RouterLinkMockModule from '../../../testing/RouterLinkMock.module';
import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
import { defaultData, collectionName } from '../../config';

const data = {
    sort: initialState.sort,
    list: [defaultData, defaultData],
    articles: { null: { name: 'test' } },
};

describe(`${collectionName} ListComponent`, () => {
    let fixture;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterLinkMockModule,
            ],
            declarations: [
                ListComponent,
            ],
        });
    });

    it('should render 2 items in list', async(inject([Router], (router) => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListComponent);
        fixture.componentInstance.data = data;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const el = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        expect(el.querySelectorAll('.box').length).toBe(2);
    })));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can swap out the default scheduler used by `debounceTime` with a TestScheduler. It will then no longer schedule future values using setInterval. I am not 100% sure if your test will succeed without the debounce running, otherwise you will have to make a true Rx test in which you let the TestScheduler run in virtual time so it will reach the desired end state as if your debounce had been triggered IRL

Comment: Thanks that sound like it can work but I am lost at "You can swap out". Can you show me how to swap the default scheduler with `TestScheduler` I could not find an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem and what helped was using the jasmine's 'done'. Though I must admit I am not familiar with the inject and I do not know what versions of angular, etc. you are running, I am trying to adapt your code, in the way that it worked for me:

```
...
describe(`${collectionName} ListComponent`, () => {
let fixture;
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            RouterLinkMockModule,
        ],
        declarations: [
            ListComponent,
        ],
        providers: [
            Router //I think you have to do that here if you do not use the inject
        ]
    });
});

it('should render 2 items in list', (done) => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListComponent);
    fixture.componentInstance.data = data;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const el = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(el.querySelectorAll('.box').length).toBe(2);
    done();
});
...
```

I am not a 100% sure that this will work for you - I have another method that stores all the references I need in a class called 'Page', like it is suggested on the angular.io page for testing. In there I also call create component and I think that is the critical part that should be covered by the 'done'. 
Not sure if that is relevant, but for reference: I am using angular 2.3.1 and karma 1.2.0 with jasmine-core 2.5.2